# Can you use CruiseControl to build Cocoa/Objective-C projects?

Tags: cocoa, testing, build-process, cruisecontrol, cruisecontrol.rb

Has anyone ever set up Cruise Control to build an OS X Cocoa/Objective-C project?

If so, is there a preferred flavor of CruiseControl (CruiseControl.rb or just regular CruiseControl) that would be easier to do this with.

I currently have a Ruby rake file that has steps for doing building and running tests, and wanted to automate this process after doing a checkin.

Also, does CruiseControl have support for git?  I couldn't find anything on the website for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you just run xcode builds via the command line (xcodebuild) which makes it simple to target from CC via an ant `<exec>`. I've been using just regular CC, not the ruby version and it works fine. Here's a barebones example:

```
<project name="cocoathing" default="build">
  <target name="build">
    <exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="CocoaThing" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="-target CocoaThing -buildstyle Deployment build" />
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

[More info on xcodebuild](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

And there does appear to be a standard git object [here](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/api/net/sourceforge/cruisecontrol/sourcecontrols/Git.html), but I don't use git so I can't tell you much more than that!

Comment: This is old, but I thought I'd update. I've switched from CruiseControl to Hudson and never looked back :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CruiseControl has a [support for git](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#git).